# Dynamically adding slide images inside slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, owl-carousel

i am trying to dynamically add images in the slider called owl slider.
The problem is that i want to clear the divs inside the

```
.owl-wrapper
```

div and then add new items on a click.
The original code is

```
 <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="../img/car1.jpg" alt="The Last of us">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="../img/car2.jpg" alt="The Last of us">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="../img/car3.jpg" alt="The Last of us">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="../img/car4.jpg" alt="The Last of us">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Now i did this

```
      $('.singleNewsItem').click(function () {

            $('#owl-demo').append('<div class="item"><img src="../img/trac1.jpg"></div>');

            });
    });
```

Somehow its adding the image outside the main slider.
Please help .
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// make sure it's initialized:
// $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel();

$('.singleNewsItem').click(function () {
    // clean the container:
    $('#owl-demo').text('');
    var img = '<div class="item"><img src="../img/trac1.jpg"></div>';
    $("#owl-demo").data('owlCarousel').addItem(img);
});
```

[**There**](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/manipulations.html) is a demo with owl manipulation examples.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hcLnq8v9/) with transistions.

Comment: Wow thanks man It Worked. Just a small question. how to clear all slides before adding this slide? i mean if i only need this one??

Comment: Can u please help me with that?

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini , you can do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/yxcvmn3c/. Updated answer